# I installed an alpha or beta, am I up to date with the final release if I keep upgrading?

Tags: upgrade, release-management

I installed an Ubuntu alpha or beta and have been keeping it up to date.

So, Should I presume that my system has automatically updated to the next alpha or beta, and will be running the official release when it's finished?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

The beta uses the repositories as they are updated -- it is not a fixed snapshot of Ubuntu as it was when the beta was released.

If there are no more updates to be installed, then congratulations! You are running the final Ubuntu release. There is nothing else you need to do.

Comment: You may want to add that anywhere along a repo's timeline that the next set of repos exist, will let you run `sudo upgrade-manager -d` to change to the next higher set of repos, in this case to the 11.04 ones.  You will also go straight (or nearly so) to the current update of 11.04.  You do not need to dist-upgrade via an alpha/beta release if there are later ones available.

Comment: Seems like your image is gone. Would you mind uploading it to stack.imgur instead?

Answer (score 11):

No; the normal upgrade process will keep you up to date.

Comment: As psusi mentioned you will stay up to date via synaptics. However, one word of warning. Back up your config files just in case. I have had updates destroy my xorg.conf before and ended up having to reinstall. Wasn't a huge deal, but hours of custimization work was undone.