# Is my system fully upgraded?

Tags: fonts, update-manager, lts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I upgraded from 10.10 beta - am I now running the official (non development) version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5675/i-upgraded-from-10-10-beta-am-i-now-running-the-official-non-development-vers)

I have this sinking feeling that my system isn't fully upgraded to the released 10.10. If nothing else I am missing the Ubuntu Font Family.
It just feels like some things aren't updating. I don't know if from release to release, beta to LTS, there aren't that many updates but I certainly haven't been seeing long lists when I start my update manager.

I just don't feel like I'm upgraded/updated to the LTS 10.10.
How can I check?
And if not, how can I update?

Answer (score 1):

Open a terminal and type:

```
cat /etc/issue
```

If it still shows 10.04, you can upgrade by going to System > Administration > Update Manager > Settings... > set "Show New Distribution Releases" to "Normal Releases" > Close > Check.  Now you should see the button for upgrading to 10.10.

Answer (score 0):

What's the output of running `apt-cache policy ttf-ubuntu-font-family` in a terminal?

Most likely you've changed your font settings a some point. Upgrades will not over-write preferences that the user has changed. [If you've been using Maverick since Beta or RC, as long as you've been upgrading regularly, you have the final release](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5829/how-can-i-upgrade-to-ubuntu-10-10-release-from-ubuntu-10-10-beta).