# How can I find the version of Ubuntu that is installed?

Tags: versions, release-management

I installed some version of Ubuntu on my VMware, but I don't know what version exactly it is. How can I find it out?

Comment: Also related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/5675/i-installed-an-alpha-or-beta-am-i-up-to-date-with-the-final-release-if-i-keep-u

Comment: None of the GUI answers are applicable to Ubuntu Studio.  Does this mean it would not be a duplicate question to pose it again but specify that the answer be for Ubuntu Studio?

Comment: I'm using Linux Mint and 'cat /etc/linuxmint/info' works too.

Answer (score 177, accepted):

Your version of Ubuntu can be determined by opening **System Settings** and then opening the **System Info** or **Details** (from 12.04) section:

[image: System Info screenshot]

This page will also tell you whether you have the 32- or 64-bit version of Ubuntu installed, as well as what processor and graphics you have, the amount of RAM installed, and your disk capacity.

You can get this info from a terminal with the command:

```
lsb_release -a
```

> Credit in part to [*htorque*](https://askubuntu.com/a/12497/24694) and [*WarriorIng64*](https://askubuntu.com/a/82218/18612)

[Note: for versions before 11.10, e.g. 11.04 this is not available this way, but see [Roland's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/35452/18612) below for workable option (basically use the 'System Monitor' icon instead]

Comment: Please also give me credit, at least for the screenshot, which I took myself and used originally in [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/82218/18612). (You can verify for yourself that a large part of this answer was a direct copy-and-paste of my answer by looking at the [edit logs](http://askubuntu.com/revisions/12494/2).)

Answer (score 108):

Apart from:

- `lsb_release -a` and
- `cat /etc/*release` ,

you can also see the version in the *GNOME System Monitor* (press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>, type `gnome-system-monitor`, and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>):

[image]

Comment: It's [considered bad practice to recommend commandline first](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/1124/24694) when there's a GUI option. Plus, that answer is, like, six months too stale. ;P

Comment: The user asked for a terminal command. Providing a GUI answer is a bonus, not a priority. :)

Comment: no longer relevant. The tab has been removed.

Comment: I like this answer better, as that "cat" tells me that I am running 16.04.1 ... whereas the UIs just say 16.04 ...

Answer (score 41):

In Ubuntu 11.10 onwards, the version of Ubuntu installed can be found by entering **System Settings > System Info** *(in newer versions like 14.04 LTS, this tab might be called **Details** instead)*:

[image: System Info screenshot]

This page will also tell you whether you have the 32- or 64-bit version of Ubuntu installed, as well as what processor and graphics you have, the amount of RAM installed, and your disk capacity.

Comment: Perhaps this answer got hijacked by the top answer at some point - but isn't this now just an exact duplicate of the top answer?

Comment: @icc97 Thanks for letting me know. My answer apparently did get "hijacked" (in fact, I made this screenshot myself and it was just taken for the other answer's edit).

Comment: Duly upvoted yours and removed my upvote for the other, pretty shocking behaviour

Comment: How do you access this window from the command-line? I'm on Xubuntu and this doesn't seem installed.

Comment: @landroni This window is part of GNOME/Unity Control Center, which may not be installed on Xubuntu. You may want to consider asking a separate question for the flavor you are using.

Answer (score 33):

```
$ lsb_release -r
Release:        10.04
```

```
$ lsb_release -c
Codename:       lucid
```

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 10.04.2 LTS
Release:        10.04
Codename:       lucid
```

```
$ cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=10.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=lucid
```

"LSB" means [Linux Standard Base](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Standard_Base), a joint project of several Linux
distributions. Its goal is to develop and promote a set of
open standards that will increase compatibility among Linux distributions.

Comment: Great! `cat /etc/lsb-release` is the only variant that also works in the official Ubuntu Docker base image.

Answer (score 22):

Quite a few ways -

**On the command line:**

1. `lsb_release -a` ▸ exact release name, version, etc.
2. `cat /etc/issue` ▸ formal release name
3. `cat /etc/issue.net` ▸ cleaner version of previous one
4. `cat /etc/debian_version`  ▸ will give you the Debian code name
5. `cat /proc/version`  ▸ will give you quite a lot of information about your kernel, when was it compiled, which GCC version has been used, etc.
6. `uname -a` ▸ will tell you about your kernel information, plus architecture (i386 ▸ 32 bit, x86_64 ▸ 64 bit)

If you like a GUI more than the command line, the System page on *System Monitor* `gnome-system-monitor` application should give you more than enough information. Release name, architecture variant, cores in the system, RAM available, and the space available on the root file system.

[image]

Comment: The command line commands very handy. Because on one of my server, the `lsb_release` wasn't getting identified only. It's the `uname` and `cat /etc/issue` that helped me. And I realized that it was **CentOS**. Thanks

Answer (score 11):

The command to find ubuntu version is,

`lsb_release -a`

or

`cat /etc/lsb-release`

or

System > About Ubuntu

Answer (score 6):

You can check it via command line.

1. Open a Terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.
2. Type:

   ```
   lsb_release -a
   ```

   and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
3. The Ubuntu version is displayed on the 'Description:' line.

For more details, see [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CheckingYourUbuntuVersion).

Comment: Will this command differentiate the alpha/beta/prod release?

Answer (score 4):

If additionally to the version you want to find out your [Ubuntu flavor](https://www.ubuntu.com/about/about-ubuntu/flavours), run the following:

```
cat /var/log/installer/media-info
```

The output should be something like:

```
Xubuntu 16.04 LTS "Xenial Xerus" - Release amd64 (20160420.1)
```

If you also want to be sure about your [Desktop Environment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_X_Window_System_desktop_environments), type:

```
echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP
```

The output should be something like:

```
XFCE
```

Answer (score 3):

There are GUI ways of checking but I prefer the Terminal.

To check your Ubuntu version using the command line:

1. Open a Terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.
2. Type: `lsb_release -a` and press Enter.

The Ubuntu version is displayed on the '**Description:**' line.

References:

[Identifying the version of Ubuntu you are using.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CheckingYourUbuntuVersion)

Answer (score 3):

This command will also find your installed Ubuntu version,

```
awk '/^Description: Ubuntu [0-9]/ {print "Ubuntu",$3; exit;}' /usr/share/python-apt/templates/Ubuntu.info
```

Example:

```
$ awk '/^Description: Ubuntu [0-9]/ {print "Ubuntu",$3; exit;}' /usr/share/python-apt/templates/Ubuntu.info
Ubuntu 14.04
```

Comment: A bit complex, but I guess it works.

Comment: guess? no, it will surely work.

Answer (score 3):

## Ubuntu Touch

If you are using Ubuntu Touch or have the Ubuntu Touch version of **System Settings** installed, you can find out more about your version information by tapping/clicking the **About this phone** button near the bottom. The information displayed may vary depending on the device you are using.

[image: Snapshot of button]
[image: Snapshot of screen]

Answer (score 2):

To find this information graphically, open the system monitor. The information you want is on the first tab:
**(NB: You cannot tell what stage of development it is at!)**
[image]

Also note mine is not saying "development branch", so the best way to tell what state your system was at when you installed it, is to know what you download :)!

Answer (score 2):

This works for most of the linux distros.

```
cat /etc/issue
```

Run this in a shell.

Answer (score 2):

`lsb_release -d`

```
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
```

`uname -r`

```
4.4.0-62-generic
```

Answer (score 2):

Run the following command.

```
hostnamectl | grep 'Operating System'
```

This will display which Ubuntu version You are using.

The command `hostnamectl` alone will give much more informations like `hostname`, `kernel version`, `architecture`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Another way, from 2 starting points:

1. From the web browser’s address bar: `ghelp:about-ubuntu`
2. Run this command (Alt + F2): `gnome-help ghelp:about-ubuntu`

Both of them have the same effect as using the Main menu > System > About Ubuntu. They open the “Display application and GNOME system help” in a page giving the same information such as https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/about-ubuntu/C/index.html (in the language in which you are using Ubuntu)