# What distribution am I using?

Tags: kubuntu-netbook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I find the version of installed Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12493/how-can-i-find-the-version-of-installed-ubuntu)

This question may find silly but here is the question..

My friend sent me a laptop from U.S. and he said he installed KDE on Ubuntu..

How do i confirm that if it is KDE over ubuntu or Kubuntu?

I am looking for some command that i can execute in terminal to find the info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check to see if the ubuntu-desktop package is installed or has ever been installed.

```
dpkg -l ubuntu-desktop
```

If you get this:-

```
No packages found matching ubuntu-desktop.
```

Then it wasn't installed from an Ubuntu medium, and so chances are it was either built up from minimal install or from a Kubuntu CD.

If you see a line that starts:-

```
un ubuntu-desktop
```

Then Ubuntu (GNOME variant) was installed but has now been removed. So chances are it was an Ubuntu install onto which KDE was added.

Comment: popey..what you said is correct. When i ran the command it returned `No packages found matching ubuntu-desktop.
`  Also my friend confirmed that he installed this from Kubuntu CD..I was looking for this only..Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 7):

In terminal type,

```
lsb_release -a
```

It will give you the similar output like mine,

```
karthick@Ubuntu-desktop:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 10.04 LTS
Release:    10.04
Codename:   lucid
```

In my case from the Distributor ID you can see that i am using Ubuntu distribution.

Comment: Here is the output of the above command `No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 10.04 LTS
Release:        10.04
Codename:       lucid`  So is it KDE over ubuntu? Please tell me

Comment: it is kde over ubuntu.

Comment: tinhed, I think this is not the KDE over ubuntu.. I got a chance to talk to my friend and he said he installed this from a Kubuntu CD..

Answer (score 0):

Try looking in Synaptic for kubuntu-desktop package installed, as apposed to just KDE packages.  I think if you have kubuntu-desktop installed it is pretty sure to be Kubuntu and not just KDE packages installed on Ubuntu, but I haven't used Kubuntu for some time.