# How to find the version of ubuntu installed?

Tags: kubuntu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I find the version of installed Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12493/how-can-i-find-the-version-of-installed-ubuntu)

How to find the version of Ubuntu installed in a machine? Is there any GUI application (like help) which can find this out. What about command line options?
Note that 
$ uname -a
gives the information about the version of linux installed. What I am looking out is to figure out the version of ubuntu like 10.10 or the upcoming 11.04