# How can I know what version of ubuntu I'm running?

Tags: versions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I find the version of installed Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12493/how-can-i-find-the-version-of-installed-ubuntu)

I have recently installed ubuntu 11.04.

My friend just asked me what beta I am using.

How can I find out?