# How can I find from console what version of ubuntu I'm using

Tags: command-line, version

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I find the version of Ubuntu that is installed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12493/how-can-i-find-the-version-of-ubuntu-that-is-installed)

There should be some easy command to find from console what version of ubuntu I'm using.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/q/12493/18612

Answer (score 3):

Here it is: `cat /etc/lsb-release`. On my system, it gives this output:

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=11.10
DISTRIB_CODENAME=oneiric
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 11.10"
```

Somewhat related, `uname -a` also gives useful information about the install, like the kernel version.

Answer (score 2):

```
karthick@Ubuntu1104:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu natty (development branch)
Release:    11.04
Codename:   natty
```