# How to setup widescreen resolutions?  Intel Graphics Media Accelerator 3000

Tags: drivers, intel-graphics, resolution, screen

I have an IBM Thinkcentre with an 'Intel Graphics Media Accelerator 3000' but Ubuntu only shows 4:3 resolutions in the display settings.

Is there an easy way to add support for widescreen resolutions? Or is it possible to install the windows display driver?

I'm using the most recent release of Ubuntu, I don't know exactly which version.

My computer:

```
 1. ThinkCentre M55 (8813-A64) Based on 8808-9HU: 
 2. Intel® Core 2 Duo Processor E6300,
 4. 2GB,
 5. 160GB 7200RPM S-ATA HDD,
 6. PCI/PCIe Small Form Factor (2x3),
 7. Intel Graphics Media Accelerator 3000,
 8. 16x DVD-ROM,
 9. Broadcom Gigabit Ethernet,
 10. DOS License
```

Comment: I don't know your anser, but I think it'll help others when you add the output to `lspci` to your question.

Comment: Find out which version of Ubuntu. http://askubuntu.com/questions/12493/how-can-i-find-the-version-of-ubuntu-that-is-installed

Comment: I got my video card info from lspci: Apparently I have an Intel 82Q963/Q965 Integrated Graphics Controller

Answer (score 1):

Have you Installed your Graphic Drivers?If you dont know so,
Go to System Settings ~> Additional Drivers And Try to install your graphic card drivers there.

Note : for me , I've Nvidia and I see 2 drivers in ' Additional Drivers ' , And When I enable 2nd one , I get some problems , Then if you have 2 drivers,too , try to test both.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not already using Ubuntu 12.04 then download the desktop image, put it on a CD or USB stick and boot off that to see whether the problem is fixed there.

Answer (score 0):

This is your answer I believe I used this with mine then wrote a script to run when I logged in .... However if you go into hibernation it will fail when you run the script again. the following link is how I got mine to work. I hope this helps you. Let me know if I can help in anyway.

[Resolution Fix for Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/311378/how-to-get-a-higher-resolution-on-ubuntu-11-04-using-an-intel-chipset)

FYI: I have a Lenovo ThinkCenter M55 (8813) as well basically the same config except i had 4 gb of ram. The above fixed my problem just had to turn off hibernation.