# What is my ubuntu version?

Tags: upgrade

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I find the version of Ubuntu that is installed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12493/how-can-i-find-the-version-of-ubuntu-that-is-installed)

I download the latest Ubuntu beta 12.10 few days ago. Now ,I completely updated after final release of Ubuntu 12.10. How can I check whether Iam still running the same beta version?