# no upgrade for 2 weeks

Tags: upgrade

Hello
 I've been using ubuntu for 2 years now. And every 1 or 2 days I had something to upgrade. But today it's been maybe 2 or 3 **weeks** since the system detected the last upgrade to do. I think something goes wrong with my Xubuntu.

What I did :
**1/** 
in synaptic I chose the repositories : *Main , universe*
And I chose the "*Main server*" to download from.

**2/**
then in a terminal :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

and I always have 0 new package to install ... Do you have the same "trouble" ? It's very strange.
Thanks for your help

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Answer (score 4):

If the version you installed 2 years ago is not [listed here](https://help.ubuntu.com/) (**11.04** for example), it is no longer supported and you should update to a newer release of Ubuntu.

To find your version of Ubuntu, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> and type `lsb_release -a` then <kbd>Enter</kbd>

[Source here](https://askubuntu.com/q/12493/12864), plus @Powerlord's comment below

Comment: Do we know this for sure?

Comment: @TomBrossman From the [Ubuntu support page](https://help.ubuntu.com/): "If your version of Ubuntu is not listed above, it is no longer supported and does not receive security or critical fixes." The versions listed as of 2012/12/22 are 8.04 LTS, 10.04 LTS, 11.10, 12.04 LTS, and 12.10.  That's the latest 3 normal releases and latest 3 LTS releases (12.04 is both).

Comment: @Powerlord The most recent version to lose support was 11.04, on [28 October](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Ubuntu_11.04_.28Natty_Narwhal.29). That's well past the '2-3 weeks' from OP's question. Because of that contradiction, it isn't safe to assume that this is the root cause. Either Robin's estimate is off by nearly 2 months, or something else is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

My version was 12.04 so still supported. Finally I had found the trouble:

In Synaptic → Settings → Repositories → Updates nothing was ticked. So I ticked *"Important Security Updates"* and *"Recommended Updates"*. Then updates worked again normally. :)

But I really don't know why they were "un-ticked". This is quite strange.

Comment: It's good to know you got your problem solved. You can accept your own answer now and close the question.