# How to install logitech mouse with ltunify?

Tags: 12.04, touchpad, logitech-unifying

Trying to install code to let Logitech Unifying software install so my mouse will work on my new Ubuntu laptop.

I think I found the program `ltunify` but can't get it to work.

I have ubuntu 12.04 LTS installed and I am not a programmer.

Initially I tried to follow the instructions from the link 
- [Is Logitech's Unifying receiver supported?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/113984/is-logitechs-unifying-receiver-supported)

I followed the quick install instructions typing in all four lines of code. It appears to load and create the ltunify directory which is says is not empty. It appears to contain hidpp20.c  keyboard.txt  notes.txt  readme.txt usbmon.awk   hidraw.c ltunify.c read-dev-usbmon.c  registers.txt.

When I enter sudo ltunify pair I get a command not found error. I have rebooted machine.

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you can start by adding a link to the "code" you have found.  Add what ubuntu version you are using.  Also add what you have tried to-do to install the "code".

Comment: I am trying to follow these directions http://askubuntu.com/questions/113984/is-logitechs-unifying-receiver-supported.  I just got a ubuntu laptop - still figuring out the interface and don't know how to figure out the ubuntu version

Comment: Please use this (http://askubuntu.com/questions/12493/how-can-i-find-the-version-of-ubuntu-that-is-installed) to find the ubuntu version.  Always edit your question with any replies.  Also please describe in detail what you have tried so far.

Comment: What mouse do you have? The mice and keyboards using Logitech unifying work out of the box on 12.04. ltunify is necessary if you want to pair additional devices to a single receiver.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your execution path does not contain `$HOME/bin`. Open the `.profile` file in your home folder and append the following block if it does not already exist:

```
# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi
```