# Am I using in this moment Xubuntu Core?

Tags: xubuntu, versions

Tell me please, am I using Xubuntu Core now?

```
xpd@xpd:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
xpd@xpd:~$
```

This has been already discussed in here:

[How can I find the version of Ubuntu that is installed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12493/how-can-i-find-the-version-of-ubuntu-that-is-installed)

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Xubuntu 14.04 with the default Xfce desktop environment the results of running `lsb_release -a` are:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

This Xubuntu installation has the default Xubuntu desktop system (*xubuntu-desktop*) package installed and Xfce is the only desktop environment installed on it. The *xubuntu-core* package is not in the default Ubuntu 14.04 repositories, and it is not installed on this system. If you are using 14.04, Xubuntu core system would not be installed by default on your system either. The *xubuntu-core* package is available for installation in the Ubuntu Software Center in 14.10 and later releases.

For more information about Xubuntu core, including the instructions for  installing the Xubuntu core version of Xubuntu, see the official [Introducing Xubuntu core](http://xubuntu.org/news/introducing-xubuntu-core/) website.