# How do I know whether I'm running a devel version of Ubuntu?

Tags: development, versions

I have found this question:

[How can I find the version of Ubuntu that is installed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12493/how-can-i-find-the-version-of-ubuntu-that-is-installed)

and so can find what version of Ubuntu I'm running.

Now, it does not seem to say anything about a devel version. Is there a specific field to look at to see whether I have an Ubuntu developer version? Which one is it?

Comment: open a terminal and run `cat /etc/issue` or `lsb_release -a`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently supported versions of Ubuntu are 12.04, 14.04 and 15.04, and Ubuntu 15.10 beta is a development build. All you need to do is to find the version of Ubuntu that is installed in *System Settings* -> *Details*.

You can also identify a development build from its release number. Ubuntu 15.10 will be released on the **10**th month of 20**15**. October, 2015 is still in the future, so Ubuntu 15.10 hasn't been released yet except for development builds.

Ubuntu 15.04 has been officially released, so there are no longer any development builds for 15.04. There are normally development builds for only the next scheduled release which is Ubuntu 15.10.

Comment: Couldn't I have 15.04 main stream version, or 15.04 development version? Isn't there always two such versions? Or is the development version 15.10?

Comment: Ubuntu 15.04 has been officially released, so there are no longer any development builds for 15.04. There are normally development builds for only the next scheduled release which is Ubuntu 15.10. Ubuntu 15.10 is scheduled to be released on October 22, 2015. Sometimes the release of a new version of Ubuntu is delayed for a week or two after the scheduled release date.

Comment: Okay, I guess that makes sense. Only I just upgraded from 14.04 to 14.10 and I had to use the `-d` option. So I suppose even though I *said* get the development version, it was just the latest, but considered unstable / unsecure because already obsolete...

Comment: There is a workaround for this which is to upgrade directly from 14.04 to 15.04 by following the instructions in: [Can I skip over releases when upgrading?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/34430/can-i-skip-over-releases-when-upgrading). Another way to do it is to only upgrade from one LTS version to the next LTS version, and run the latest non-LTS version is VirtualBox if you need to install an updated or new package from it.