# Do I have ubuntu version 16.04 or 16.10

Tags: upgrade, 16.10

I have set the "Software and Updates" app set to inform me of new LTS releases of the OS (ubuntu Studio 16.04 installed).  16.10 has been out for a while now, but I do not remember getting a notification.  I know for sure that I did not upgrade to 16.10 unless it happened without my knowing. I checked the version in the Linux terminal and it reports 16.04, so I tried `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`, but it returned: `0 upgraded, 0 newly installed`...

Either I am running 16.10 and the version is reported wrong (in the Linux terminal) or I am still running 16.04 and something else is wrong, but which one is it?

As for this being a possible duplicate on how to upgrade:  I need to know if I am being shown the wrong OS version, or already upgraded first.  I already had an answer on "How to upgrade" which did not work.

Comment: What does `lsb_release -a` say about your Ubuntu version?

Comment: Wrong command, use `sudo do-release-upgrade`. The command `dist-upgrade` only adds held back packages, it does not upgrade the release version. Read this  http://askubuntu.com/questions/110477/how-do-i-upgrade-to-a-newer-version-of-ubuntu

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I upgrade to a newer version of Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/110477/how-do-i-upgrade-to-a-newer-version-of-ubuntu)

Comment: I will try the other command.

It may be a duplicate for another question as far as the answer is concerned, but "How do I upgrade... " is still an entirely different question, as I am not sure if I am already upgraded or not.  I asked If my version is being reported wrong...

I will find out now, please stand by.

Comment: I tried the command from @Mark Kirby, and it seems to work, but I will have to hold off on upgrading until I close shop tonight.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I find the version of Ubuntu that is installed?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/12493/how-can-i-find-the-version-of-ubuntu-that-is-installed)

Comment: `uname -i` Show me the output of this , Why you wana upgrade to 16.10 when 21.10 exists . Trust me you can upgrade to 21.10 too whithout loosing your data If your system is 64 bit , (I am working on a bash script which will help older 64 bit versions of ubuntu to directly upgrade to latest version by modifying some files repository and other stuff, and then running sudo apt upgrade just upgrades to the newest release, it is tested on 5+ systems and worked correctly :) I hope so you understand )

Answer (score 2):

**Check the version of Ubuntu**

You can check what Ubuntu version you have by typing `lsb_release -a` in terminal.

OR

Open **System Settings**  ->  Click on **Details** and you can see the version under the Ubuntu logo.

[image: Ubuntu 14.04 Long Term Support System Details]

EDIT: (as requested)

**To upgrade to the newer version of Ubuntu**

- Via Command line

Run `do-release-upgrade` in a terminal

- Via GUI

1. Run the update manager
2. Click the check button to see if there is a new version available
3. Click the install button a message will appear if there is a new version available.

[image]

Comment: I did that, hence:  "version 16.04 reported in terminal".

I do not have "Details" in system settings on Ubuntu Studio, it has the XFCE desktop, not Unity.  Besides from everything I can read the terminal is the more reliable way to check.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question: typing lsb_release -a in terminal did report the current version I had installed (16.04) right.  The command "sudo apt-get dist-upgrade" that I got from here:  [How to Upgrade Ubuntu 16.04 to Ubuntu 16.10](https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/upgrade-ubuntu-16-04-to-ubuntu-16-10) did not work.  It did not tell me why, nor if it did nothing because I was already upgraded (the reason for my question).

@Mark Kirby commented: "Wrong command, use sudo do-release-upgrade. The command dist-upgrade only adds held back packages, it does not upgrade the release version. Read this askubuntu.com/questions/110477/…"  When I did, an upgrade to 16.10 was available.  This told me two things:  I was running 16.04, and I could upgrade to 16.10, which I just got finished with a few minutes ago. So now all I have to do is keep my fingers crossed that it got rid of a few problems I had, and that it did not open a whole new can of worms.

If someone can, please upgrade Mark Kirby's comment to an answer (#1), that would be dandy.

Comment: added it to my answer :)