# Can anyone help me to find out which version of Ubuntu we use?

Tags: versions

I need to be able to find out what version of Ubuntu we are using. I have no IT person who can help anymore.
Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to do so you don't need to have any kind of programming knowledge. I highly suggest you to go System settings >> System details or software details!

I hope it helps. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Open terminal and type the command:

```
lsb_release -a
```

Comment: Why this isn't called `ubuntu-version` or similar, I don't know, I can never remember the command.

Answer (score 0):

There can be many ways to do this-

- You could find *System Info* in *System Settings*, or search for the same in the program menu, which would give you a GUI overview.
- In terminal, enter `cat /etc/os-release`.
- Or, in terminal enter `lsb_release -a`.
- Or, type `hostnamectl` in the terminal.

If you need more details about kernels etc., you can type `uname -a` in the terminal. Read man page of the same at `man uname` for more details.

For more details, you can see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12493/how-can-i-find-the-version-of-ubuntu-that-is-installed).