# If I install a beta or alpha will I have to reinstall when it is finally released?

Tags: upgrade, development, release-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I upgraded from a beta - am I now running the official (non development) version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5675/i-upgraded-from-a-beta-am-i-now-running-the-official-non-development-version)

So with beta 1 just around the corner, I was wondering: will I have to reinstall Ubuntu if I install beta 1 when the final release comes out or will it update itself to release quality?

I'm eager to install 11.04 but don't really want to bother if I'll have to install all over again (losing customisations) in a month's time.

Comment: related to http://askubuntu.com/questions/5675/i-upgraded-from-10-10-beta-am-i-now-running-the-official-non-development-vers