# What is this install icon on the launcher on my installed system?

Tags: installation, 11.10

I'm using the 11.10 version since the RC which I used to update every time an update is issued. The final release is now out and I still see the "Install RELEASE" icon on the dock. If I install all the updates the normal way (through the update manager) what would be my system status: the final release or just an updated RC? Do I have to re-launch the installer from that icon to get the release (knowing that I'll have to re-do every step the installer requires)?

Here is an amateur made screenshot of the icon I'm talking about:

[image]

If I'm missing something please guide me. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate - [I upgraded from an Alpha or Beta, am I up-to-date if I keep upgrading?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5675/i-upgraded-from-an-alpha-or-beta-am-i-up-to-date-if-i-keep-upgrading)

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the install release icon on the dock. I also had a RC which I kept upgrading. Technically if you keep updating you should be runnning the final release. So not sure why you have that icon on the dock.

Comment: @Nik: I uploaded the icon screenshot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not have the Install icon anywhere on the installed system, regardless of whether it was a beta, an RC or the final release. The installer and associated packages are usually removed at the end of installation.

Try removing ubiquity with

```
sudo apt-get purge ubiquity*
```

Ubiquity is the Ubuntu installer. Instead of being removed, for reasons unknown, it must have been retained after the installation. Removing its packages manually seems to be a logical step.

Comment: The icon is gone, Thanks. Could you just elaborate more what just happened?