# What is this 'Install RELEASE' icon on my Unity dock?

Tags: system-installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is this install icon on the launcher on my installed system?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66086/what-is-this-install-icon-on-the-launcher-on-my-installed-system)

Upon a fresh install of Ubuntu 12.04, there's this icon on the Unity dock called "Install RELEASE." What is this and what is it supposed to install? Do I need this or can I remove it?

Thanks

Comment: Have you installed or used remastersys?

Comment: no actually, what is that?

Comment: Mostly, its a full system backup.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/66086/what-is-this-install-icon-on-the-launcher-on-my-installed-system Looks alot like that?

Comment: That icon is the "Install Ubuntu" icon, in the Live system. The `ubiquity` package is not removed by the installation process. You can remove that package safely with `sudo apt-get remove ubiquity*`. No harm. I had that icon in past. See [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/66092/61218)