# How to upgrade to beta from alpha or to beta 2 from beta 1?

Tags: upgrade, update-manager, partial-upgrade, beta

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I upgraded from an alpha or beta - am I up to date if I keep upgrading?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5675/i-upgraded-from-an-alpha-or-beta-am-i-up-to-date-if-i-keep-upgrading)

How to upgrade to 12.04 beta 1 from 12.04 alpha 2?

Comment: Same solution in those answers apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply use apt-get

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```