# Would I be able to get the final release of ubuntu 12.04 if I upgrade now?

Tags: upgrade, 12.04

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I installed an alpha or beta, am I up to date with the final release if I keep upgrading?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5675/i-installed-an-alpha-or-beta-am-i-up-to-date-with-the-final-release-if-i-keep-u)

As ubuntu 12.04 is in the final beta testing now, I was wondering that if I upgraded the distribution on my machine (ubuntu 11.10 now if that info is needed), then would i be able to update to the final release through my software update channel or would i have to reinstall the OS?