# From Ubuntu 12.04 beta2 upgrade to 12.04

Tags: upgrade, 12.04

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I installed an alpha or beta, am I up to date with the final release if I keep upgrading?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5675/i-installed-an-alpha-or-beta-am-i-up-to-date-with-the-final-release-if-i-keep-u)
>   [How do I upgrade from 10.04 or 11.10 to 12.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110477/how-do-i-upgrade-from-10-04-or-11-10-to-12-04)

Help!Please I why not,I go to the update Center and I find not.

Comment: See also: http://askubuntu.com/questions/5675/i-installed-an-alpha-or-beta-am-i-up-to-date-with-the-final-release-if-i-keep-u