# Upgrading from 12.04 beta 2 to stable 12.04

Tags: upgrade, apt, 12.04, beta

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I installed an alpha or beta, am I up to date with the final release if I keep upgrading?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5675/i-installed-an-alpha-or-beta-am-i-up-to-date-with-the-final-release-if-i-keep-u)

How to upgrade from beta 2 release of 12.04 to stable release of 12.04? Do I need to create a new installing disk for upgrading, or can I update it via APT? (And yes, I know that upgrading via APT is not recommended) Update manager didn't say anything about upgrading to 12.04, so I tried sudo apt-get dist-upgrade, but it didn't work either.

Comment: Hi Cybeet, if you've been updating the beta normally, you're already running 12.04 LTS final. Congrats, and have fun!