# WIll I be able to upgrade the developer preview to the full version?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

WIll I be able to upgrade the ubuntu touch developer preview to the full version? I installed the developer version and was curious if when released , would i be able to upgrade to the full version on my nexus 7, thank you

Comment: Related (but probably shouldn't be closed as a duplicate): [I installed an alpha or beta, am I up to date with the final release if I keep upgrading?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5675/i-installed-an-alpha-or-beta-am-i-up-to-date-with-the-final-release-if-i-keep-u)

Answer (score 1):

There are and will be frequent updates of the Ubuntu Touch Developer Preview. See [here](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-touch-preview/daily-preinstalled/): The latest as I write this is from March 23, that's the same day. So time by time more functions will be added and the developer will get a better and more complete basis system in order to test their applications and to test the whole system.

This is an imminent prerequisite for the application developer therfore it would not make sense for canonical to continue working on the system somewhere behind closed doors and finally come out with a final release.

So at the end the Developer Preview will be the final release or at least very similar to that.