# Is the development version of Ubuntu cloned from the immediate previous stable release?

Tags: release-management

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 and saw that it showed Ubuntu 13.10 while installing. I could confirm I installed Ubuntu 14.04 when I did this on a terminal:

```
lsb_release -a
```

and got this as output:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04 (Developement release)
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

So are the development versions directly cloned from the previous stable releases? If yes, doesn't a radical change like the change to [Mir](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Mir/) from [Xorg](http://www.x.org/wiki/) be difficult to implement since the underlying platform itself change?

**P.S.:** I am not sure whether this should be on AO, as this is a question on development release but then such questions have no scope to be asked anywhere else.

Comment: This is on-topic as it is not about a 'problem' with a development release.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is there a Ubuntu+1 immediately after a stable release?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/370996/why-is-there-a-ubuntu1-immediately-after-a-stable-release)

Answer (score 0):

The development versions are daily built and they're different from stable releases.
Currently, Ubuntu 14.04 hasn't come to UI freezing stage, so the 'Ubuntu 10.10' thing lurks around.

see [Ubuntu 14.04 Release Schedule](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/TrustyTahr/ReleaseSchedule) for more details about Ubuntu's release management procedures.

Comment: Actually it's possible to upgrade to the development version even before daily ISOs are released (by using the unsupported Debian-style technique of editing `sources.list` and doing `apt-get dist-upgrade`). The daily ISOs are a way of testing if the development release installs, as well as a convenient way to get it. I believe at the very beginning of a development release--which is just after the release of the preceding stable release--that it consists mostly of files copied over from the stable release. But I'm not really sure how this works. If you know you may want to expand this answer.