# When does Ubuntu development begins on the next version after the current release?

Tags: release-management

When does Ubuntu development begins on the next version after the current release?  Is it like 2 months after the current release, several weeks?  I am just wondering, since I want the daily build of Ubuntu 14.10 if their is some.  Also, To they release the daily-build the same day that the begin development, or is it like a week?

Comment: Related http://askubuntu.com/questions/370996/why-is-there-a-ubuntu1-immediately-after-a-stable-release?lq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

13.10 was released on October 17th 2013 and Trusty was [open for development](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel/2013-October/037724.html) the 21st. So it's just a matter of days.

Subscribe to [ubuntu-devel](https://lists.ubuntu.com/mailman/listinfo/ubuntu-devel) or look at https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel/ for the announcement.