# Are there long-term disadvantages to installing 22.04 before the Release?

Tags: apt, updates, 22.04

I'm in the process of setting up a new PC.

Is there any long-term disadvantage to installing the Ubuntu 22.04 Beta now before the RC and before the Release? I mean things like some configuration files being persistently worse than if I had installed it after the official release? Or some packages being permanently degraded if I install now?

I don't care if the system is temporarily unstable until 22.04 officially releases. But after the release I want the system to be exactly as good as if I would have delayed installing 22.04 until after the official release.

Comment: Short answer is no, not really.

Comment: Hello. There is one that you may find important. You can not post questions here about beta or pre release software.

Comment: If you want a *dirtier* file-system, with little bits (installed during *alpha* or *beta* stages that are evidence of the *alpha* or *beta* install only & not a *finished* product install) then maybe it's then worthwhile.  Those *dirty* bits do **not** impact the running of the system, but the *left-overs* aren't always cleaned up as it's the *alpha* or *beta* tester's job to do the cleanup (it's not a *finished* or *final* product!)  These *dirty bits* should **not** impact operation at all.

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04 doesn't yet exist; it's currently the *development* release Ubuntu *jammy* and remains that until it reaches RC state which isn't expected until after 14 April 2022, and isn't on-topic here until release on 21 April 2022.  https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/jammy-jellyfish-release-schedule/23906  Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic.  For support issues with Ubuntu *jammy* you'll need to use a #ubuntu-next or #ubuntu+1 site (IRC, UF etc)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will the alpha/beta ISO become official after Release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/276181/will-the-alpha-beta-iso-become-official-after-release). Note the third bullet point in the answer.

Comment: If you wish to report bugs, firstly thank you for helping test the release, but please see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs and use a #ubuntu+1 site such as IRC, https://ubuntuforums.org/ etc. *This site isn't tracked for ubuntu+1 or #ubuntu-next issues*   Also don't forget it's still in *testing* with *beta* freeze just *hit* & *beta* release on 31-March-2022  *Your question is specific to 22.04 as I read it & thus off-topic as it's not yet a released product...

Comment: FYI:  I've been running jammy for a few days short of six months, being on the development cycle now for years; effects are minimal - but evident if you do disk byte comparisons.   It's essentially *equivalent* as far as execution/runtime goes, but disk byte comparisons show differences as it can be *messier*.

Comment: @guiverc Thank you for answering and explanation how things work here. This is the first time I used this page (I used openSUSE for around a decade before switching to Ubuntu now).