# Upgrading from *Ubuntu beta

Tags: upgrade, beta

I'd like to know if I decide to install an *Ubuntu beta right now (Lubuntu), will I be able to upgrade to non-beta as soon as it comes out (17 August), or will I need to make a new installation?

Comment: This is answered already from http://askubuntu.com/questions/5675/i-installed-an-alpha-or-beta-am-i-up-to-date-with-the-final-release-if-i-keep-u

Comment: I did a search and could not find it. thank you NGRhodes, seems like I can install the beta right now and just keep on updating.