# Am I being served a beta release of 13.10?

Tags: upgrade, 13.10

Today, I followed the instructions at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SaucyUpgrades (Ubuntu Desktops 13.04 to 13.10). When I got to step #6, the release notes popped up, and the first two lines said:

> **Welcome to the Ubuntu 'Saucy Salamander' development release**
>
> *This is still a BETA release. Do not install it on production
>   machines.*

Is my system trying to get outdated files, or is is safe to ignore those notes?

Comment: I had the same. At the end I decided to download ISO and install it from USB.

Comment: same problem here... this is very strange...

Comment: Looks to be a bug with the links in that document, however the warning is pretty much irrelevant nowadays, since Saucy's repositories are stable released, and your updates will be received the same way to bring you to what's on the ISOs and in the -updates repositories,.

Comment: I'd start by learning how [these files](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy/main/dist-upgrader-all/current/) work. If you're not just hitting an outdated mirror ([there are many](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors)), perhaps you'll find a stale local cache or uncover a bug in the upgrader.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that the message has not been updated already. The files are the official 13.10 release but since the message still shows the previous text (when it was Beta) it shows like that to any users that tries to update.

The same thing happened with 12.10 to 13.04 and 12.04 to 12.10. If you do wait about a day (up to a week) the message should change to "Welcome to the Ubuntu 'Saucy Salamander'".

Give it time while the developers work on this "high priority" bug ;). It confused me too until I updated.

Comment: Haha, "high priority" indeed ;) (seriously though, I thought release notes should be updated before releasing)

Thanks for the comparison with previous updates; it's good to know that I can safely upgrade and that the problem doesn't lie in my my repo settings.

Answer (score 3):

13.10 is not a beta release anymore.  13.10 is a stable release.  **If you were on the Beta release ISOs, or are installing the Beta release ISOs, the system should still update to the latest versions in the repos, as your updates should still be applied because the repositories used are the same as the full released versions now.**

This is an issue of where the community docs were just out of date.

The documentation has been updated to reflect that it is no longer a beta release.

Comment: But I tried just 1 hour ago.. And still presented the BETA message. Tried both with italian and official server. So the explanation is that someone forgot to update the message?

Comment: @Pisu the beta images will update automatically to the stable release data, because its the same repositories, you should be able to safely ignore that error.  Read the bolded area of my post now.

Comment: @ThomasW. Yes I know that 13.10 is a stable release now, which is why I was confused by the beta message. Good to know the repos are the same and I can ignore the message. (As of 8:00am UTC+8, 26 October 2013, both the Australian server and the Main server still show the beta message, even though [these notes](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy/main/dist-upgrader-all/current/) has been updated)

Answer (score 2):

Even if it is labelled a beta release you will be getting the same files as the stable release.

For more info:

[I installed an alpha or beta, am I up to date with the final release if I keep upgrading?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5675/i-installed-an-alpha-or-beta-am-i-up-to-date-with-the-final-release-if-i-keep-u)

Answer (score -1):

Always hashcheck downloaded isos from the official releases at releases.ubuntu.com.  The check will not only detect transmission errors but detect old or altered versions.

---

If the problem persists, the cause may be far in the past.  You cannot expect official updates to fix everything in an altered iso.

Comment: Agreed, that's good advice for all downloaded installers in general. However, the link I posted uses the Update Manager, not ISOs.

Comment: The question was not about the ISO image, but about upgrading from 13.04 to 13.10 with upgrade manager.