# Is there such a thing as the "go live" for LTS pre-release builds of Ubuntu?

Tags: server, lts, release-management

For certain pre-release builds of software products it is guaranteed that they can be used already in production - and more importantly can be upgraded to the final version.

Is there such a thing for Ubuntu's LTS versions?

---

Alternatively, do you have any guidance for the scenario described below.

I want to set up a new Ubuntu Server and would like to start preparations for this right now. Does it make sense to use the daily build [before the release](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/TrustyTahr/ReleaseSchedule) and set it up already, despite potential bugs? Will the system be equivalent to a freshly installed system after the final release, if I run `apt-get dist-upgrade`? Or would I have to start over anyway?

Obviously I would prefer not to use 12.04.4 right now and then upgrade to 14.04 in a month. Instead it seems to make sense to start with a daily build. But can it be upgraded to the final release version?

Comment: A apt-get dist-upgrade may take you to 14.10. If you just do normal updates it will be the final. Its just that you should not expect that everything works all the time. If a critical server probably better to wait several months before installing. If not final you also have more log files and old .debs as a lot may change. Often best to do a new install just to in effect do major houseclean. Of course if you know how to houseclean and are willing to put up with a possibility of issues, you can install now. But it really is for those who want to test and help on bugs.

Comment: Related (and maybe a duplicate): http://askubuntu.com/q/5675/65926

Comment: @EricCarvalho: yep, this is very close to my question indeed. Voting to close this one.