# Ubuntu 14.04, Upgrade Path for Final Beta -> Release?

Tags: release-management

I need to build out a new server with long term support.

Ubuntu 14.04 LTS is in Final Beta. See [Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (Trusty Tahr) Final Beta released](http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2014/03/28/ubuntu-14-04-lts-trusty-tahr-final-beta-released/).

I'm OK with using a Final Beta before the Release build is released. But I'm not clear if there's an upgrade path from the alphas and betas to release. (If there's no upgrade path, I'd prefer not to use it since this includes a mailbox migration).

**Question**: will there be an upgrade path from 14.04 Final Beta to 14.04 Release?

Note: this could be a duplicate of [I installed an alpha or beta, am I up to date with the final release if I keep upgrading?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5675/i-installed-an-alpha-or-beta-am-i-up-to-date-with-the-final-release-if-i-keep-u) If the process for 14.04 is the same as previous, then its a duplicate. However, [Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (Trusty Tahr) Final Beta released](http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2014/03/28/ubuntu-14-04-lts-trusty-tahr-final-beta-released/) does not appear to discuss it.

Comment: It's a duplicate. Doing the upgrades will get you to the final release.

Comment: Thanks chaskes. You should answer so I can accept. Also, I can't cast a close vote on this. Would you mind?

Comment: Thanks, but It's such a clear dupe there's no point in answering since I have nothing to add to the other answer. I voted to close, so I'm sure it will be gone soon.